# WordPress: Getting "Newer Posts" and "Older Posts" links on a Specialized Page Template

Tags: pagination

I am using a Specialized Page Template to display list of posts. I am using the following code for that:

```
<?php 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'paged' => $paged
);
$all_posts = get_posts($args); 
?>

<?php foreach ( $all_posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );  ?>
/* the loop */
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now I want to put "Newer Posts" and "Older Posts" links below it. `next_posts_link()` and `previous_posts_link()` prints nothing here. How can I add these two links on this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using WP_Query as shown in the following code. To know more information on this visit [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link#Usage_when_querying_the_loop_with_WP_Query).

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=5&paged=' . $paged ); 


if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

    // the loop
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
        the_title();
    endwhile; 

next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages );
previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );

// clean up after our query
wp_reset_postdata();
endif;  ?>
```